# Initial speed of a released object from a moving object

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, velocity, free-fall

For example, if a helicopter is moving upwards in constant velocity of 20 m/s and at some height an object is released from the helicopter, why does the object has an initial velocity of 20 m/s and not 0 m/s?

Comment: If someone holds the object out the window and you look at the helicopter and the object from the ground, is the object moving (20 m/s) or is it stationary (0 m/s) as seen by you?

Comment: If the helicopter is moving at 20m/s, then how fast is the object moving at the instant _before_ it is released? When you have learned the relationship between force, and mass, and acceleration ([Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion)), then you will understand why the speed of the object can not _instantaneously_ change when it is released.